# "Slowing" output

Tags: c++, character

I've a question that I don't know how to explain well, but i will try... for example, in some games the text output is "slow", writing char one after another, and not all the phrase in one time... so, how can I replicate this behavior?

I think this way... I can do a loop and where I write a char and usleep for 1 millisecond, write a char and usleep, and so on... there is another way or this is the only/best/simple way I can implement this trick? I'm trying to do this in c++, but other suggestion are welcome.

Comment: You could make a class that helps do what you described. Then you can reuse it easily.

Comment: Do you have a main loop for the game? if this is the case, you can normally have a time reference, either yours or a based on a true clock

Answer (score 0):

Well yes usleep is a solution, but You should thread it or it will slow your game too. 1ms might not be enough visually speaking though. I suggest that you make some test in order to see.

The output? is made on a terminal? If so, maybe you could use some term capacities too.

Edit: You can use a clock aswell !!

Comment: the output will be on a text area... what do you mean using a clock?

Comment: Admitting that you are in a loop and u want a precise pause (not performance dependante like a sleep() call), lets say  1sec, You get the clock() or ctime() at the first letter printed and then you compare the ellapsed time using an if statement, when it has reached 1sec you print another letter and your re-initialize the clock/time and so on... I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate thread just to update a piece of text would be somewhat of a waste of resources if you ask me.
They way I'd recommend doing this is to define a number of characters that are supposed to be shown on screen in one second and then count the number of milliseconds since the last time you updated the text. Then you multiply by that value

Example:

```
float charsPerSecond = 60/1000;
float lastUpdated;
...
int nrChars = (int) (charsPerSecond * (currentTime - lastUpdated));
//output nrChars characters
lastUpdated = currentTime;
```